# Batch file to poll a folder for new files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, ftp, batch-file

I want to write a batch file which is triggered whenever a new file is added to a particular folder.

I can schedule a task using schtasks. But I am looking for a solution based upon interrupt kind of thing rather than polling. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What OS are you trying to do this on?

Comment: I am working on windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do what you want, it's called iNotify on Linux/Unix, where the OS can run a script based on activity in a directory that it is "watching". Windows and Mac have similar functionality, it's called by different names.

This [question on stackoverflow covers all the options for the various OSes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows).

[JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) is a nice option which is written in Java and can run on all OSes. It requires writing some Java code, not sure if you're looking for that sort of option.

Answer (score 2):

Batch can't polling, but you can try this VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

Const Path = "%userprofile%\Documents\Folder"
Const Interval = 1
Const Delay = 60

Dim oWSH, oFSO, oWMI, oEvent, oTarget, colEvents
Dim sPath, sDrive, sFolder, sNewPath

Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oWSH.CurrentDirectory = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
sPath = oWSH.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(Path)
sPath = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(sPath)
If Not oFSO.FolderExists(sPath) Then oFSO.CreateFolder(sPath) 
sDrive = oFSO.GetDriveName(sPath)
sFolder = Replace(Mid(sPath, 3) & "\", "\", "\\", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colEvents = oWMI.ExecNotificationQuery( _
  "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent" _
  & " WITHIN " & CStr(Interval) _
  & " WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile'" _
  & " AND TargetInstance.Drive='" & sDrive & "'"_
  & " AND TargetInstance.Path='" & sFolder & "'") 

Do 
  Set oEvent = colEvents.NextEvent()
  sNewPath = Year(Now) & "_" & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & "_" & Right("0" & Day(Now), 2)
  sNewPath = oFSO.BuildPath(sPath, sNewPath)
  If Not oFSO.FolderExists(sNewPath) Then oFSO.CreateFolder(sNewPath)
  Set oTarget = oEvent.TargetInstance
  WScript.Sleep Delay * 1000
  On Error Resume Next
  oFSO.MoveFile oTarget.Name, oFSO.BuildPath(sNewPath, oFSO.GetFileName(oTarget.Name))
  On Error Goto 0
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the tool at http://www.myassays.com/folder-poll to do just this.  It's a Windows application that includes a user-friendly manager application to allow easy configuration.  Also, there is an XML configuration option.  The actual folder polling runs as a Windows service (so starts automatically on each restart).  When a new file is detected in a polled folder an application can be launched automatically (you can specify your own custom command line arguments).  It can do other things like copy/move files too. Also, activity can be logged to a log file and there are other advanced operations.  Note, this is a commercial tool (i.e. not free).