# Windows: Automated PDF compression (Hot folder)

Tags: windows, pdf, compression

In Windows, is there a way to monitor a folder and *automatically* compress a PDF that is placed in it?

(by compression, I mean make a PDF smaller (I.e. not zip it), similar to using the reduce file size command in Acrobat).

I know Acrobat has a tool for compressing PDFs which can be batched, but I need it to run automatically when a PDF is added to a folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to poll a folder for new files](http://superuser.com/questions/579245/batch-file-to-poll-a-folder-for-new-files).

Answer (score 0):

There is a product that will do that: http://www.neuxpower.com/products/nxpowerlite-file-server/features/ (not affiliated). To the best of my knowledge, there's no native way to do that in Windows.

It's not the only product. A google search for [automated PDF compression](https://www.google.ch/search?q=automated%20pdf%20compression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp) should reveal more software that can do that.